# AngularFireAuth. Create user with additional field

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-authentication, angularfire, angularfire2

Is it possible to create users in Firebase with an additional field?
In my code, I can create them with "email", and "password".

```
  this.af.auth.createUser({
    name: formData.value.name,  // gives error*
    email: formData.value.email,
    password: formData.value.password
  }).then(
```

*error:

signup.component.ts (26,9): Argument of type '{ name: any; email: any; password: any; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'EmailPasswordCredentials'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'name' does not exist in type 'EmailPasswordCredentials'.

I'd like to add additional fields, like "date of birth", "displayName", etc.

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/users) you cannot do this.  However, you can add these additional fields into the data.  I use a User Settings structure, where the same User Id is, and then you have a full structure available.

I use a folder of the base data structure, UserSettings, to hold the custom fields, and then get this data at the same time as I handle the authentication, in an Angular data provider.

```
"UserSettings": {
    // User Specified Settings should be read/write by the user
    "$user_id": {
        ".read": "$user_id === auth.uid",
        ".write": "$user_id === auth.uid"
    }
}
```

Firebase Data

```
+ - /UserSettings
    + /<user id string>
        + Name
        + BirthDate
```

Comment: is it possible to do this sending all the fields to Cloud Functions (/for Firebase) and do both things with a single call from the user?

Comment: I am not sure of your question. It depends on how you are writing your data, and I do write a JSON object with that hierarchy under user id.  Writing this as an object works with the structure defined, if that helps.

Comment: thank you Steven for the reply, put "short": i have a website which, in the registration form, needs email+password+other fields. I dont want to add those fields only after the registration succeeds (using the createUserWithEmailAndPassword callback), because if there is any problem between successful signup & callback, the email is taken without all the fields being stored. Can i achieve this by sending a JSON with mail+pw+fields to Cloud Functions and do Firebase Auth + Firestore user fields from there?

Comment: I think you need to break this up in your flow.  Validate and create the user, and then when that passes, update the other information in the storage.  This would also allow people to change these values (email address, name, etc) and save these into the same location from the proper page on your site.